# How to get pgrouting source and target value using openlayers 2/3?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, openlayers, pgrouting, routing

Is there anyone can teach me how to get the pgrouting's source and target parameters in openlayers 2/3? I plan to get those parameters by click the OSM map layer. Currently, I can only get the lonlat x and y values, but my this is not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a WMS GetFeatureInfo request to query for map feature attributes:

- [Geoserver Tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html)
- [OpenLayers Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-popup.html)